# Всевозможные сочетания string-ов.

Tags: stl, c++

Здравствуйте!

Такая задача:
Есть

```
struct Sochet{      
    vector<string> sb;// Вектор новых сочетаний 
}soch[2000];// Вектор новых сочетаний
```

И есть vector<string> str;

Нужно получить всевозможные комбинации...

Напимер str содержит "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"...

а комбинации должны быть такими:
AB
AC
AD
AE
....
ABC
ABD
....
ABCD
ABCE
....
....
BC
BD
BE
...
Надеюсь понятно... Весь вопрос сошел на битовые операции...
Я думаю. что можно брать число, и смотреть какие в нем биты не нулевые и соответственно выбирать из массива строки по индексу.... Вопрос, как узнать номера битов в чиле, значения которых отличны от нуля?
Спасибо.

Comment: Например так

     if (n & (1 << i))
       printf ("bit %d is set\n", i);

для 32-бит чисел. (для 0 <= i < 32)

Comment: А можно по подробнее? (n & (1 << i)), что здесь что? У меня массив из N элементов(всего комбинаций 0 и 1 = 2^N), мне нужно бежать по нему и выбирать элементы с теми номерами, индексы которых при умножении(побитовом) не дали 0. Как-то так... Сам запутался.

Comment: @Alerr, IMHO вот, что Вы описали. 

    // per.c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    
    
    int
    main (int ac, char *av[])
    {
      char *str = av[1] ? av[1] : "abc";
      int  i, j, n, l = strlen(str), k = (1 << l);
    
      for (n = 0; n < k; n++) {
        char res[l+1];
        for (i = j = 0; j < l; j++) 
          if (n & (1 << j))
     res[i++] = str[j];
        if (i > 1) {
          res[i] = 0;
          puts(res);
        }
      }
    
      return 0;
    }

    gcc per.c; a.out
    ab
    ac
    bc
    abc

Дальше сами разберетесь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Честно говоря, не очень понял, как в пришли к необходимости работы с байтами, поэтому предложу несколько более очевидный вариант - рекурсивную функцию

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

void permutation(std::string str, int from, int size)
{
    if(from == size - 1)
    {
        for(int a = 0; a < size; a++)
            std::cout << str[a] << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = from; i < size; i++)
        {

            std::swap(str[from], str[i]);
            permutation(str, from + 1, size);
            std::swap(str[from], str[i]);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string str = "abcde";

    for(int i = 2; i < str.length(); ++i)
        permutation(str, 0, i);

    return 0;
}
```