# Обработка базы данных

Tags: база-данных, pascal

Нужно обработать много много строк таблицы, фильтруя их по столбцам. Начну пожалуй сразу с примера.

Пример столбцов(фильтров): `Имя-Фамилия-Возраст-Зачет(1-зачет,0-не зачет)`

Пример данных (строки):

```
Иван Иванов 20 1

Петр Петров 23 0

Иван Петров 23 1

Петр Иванов 21 0
```

P.S. строка расчленяется на массивы столбцов, то есть отдельный массив имен, фамилий возраста и результата, а также соответствующие массивы с вариантами.

`Иван, Петр, Иван, Петр` - массив столбца

`Иван, Петр` - массив вариантов столбца

Теперь, мне нужно по всем вариантам фильтра вывести количество Зачетов и Не зачетов.
Пример: `Иван 2 0` - с фильтром на имя `"Иван"` `2 зачет и 0 не зачет`

`Петров 1 1` - с фильтром на фамилию `"Петров"` `1 зачет и 1 не зачет`.

И так нужно вывести по каждому фильтру результат. В данном случае будет 12 вариантов фильтра.
Часть из них: `"Иван"`; `"Петр"`; `"Иван"` и `20` (возраст); `"Петров"` и `23` и т.д.

Пока что у меня только одна идея - сделать несколько вложенных циклов и в последний засунуть 12 `if`, что конечно очень муторно, потому что на самом деле у меня больше фильтров и значений, прописать 64 `if` как то не очень хочется.

UPD я понимаю, что это можно решить через `С++` или `SQL`, но я работаю на паскале, и мне кажется тут это не реально , вот нашел подобные задачи [пример 1](http://www.cyberforum.ru/c-beginners/thread1487332.html) и [пример2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/257698/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-string-%D0%BE%D0%B2), я в С еще не шарю, кто-нибудь мог бы объяснить решение?

UPD2 Вот это что в реальности. Нужно найти все виды комбинаций фильтров и проход к ним. К примеру фильтр `51%` в первом столбце, количество `проходов` (1) = 1. И так мне надо найти для всех комбинаций, к примеру - `51%` в первом столбце и `23%`; `25%` в третьем столбце и прогноз `12` и так далее. Сейчас я могу найти все это по отдельности, то есть обработать только 1 вариант комбинации. Я загоняю данные столбцов `Проц1` и `Проход` в программу и потом сравниваю с процентами от 1 до 100, и для каждого от 1 до 100 выходит количество `Проходов` 1 и 0.
[image: Что в реальности]

Comment: покажите структуру базы данных с более реальними полями. так легче

Comment: @hichock У вас данные в каком формате вообще: в файле лежат, программа их у пользователя спрашивает, может они уже в нормальной базе данных, если да, то в какой ? И с чего вы взяли, что на паскале нельзя чего то написать, первые версии Windows на паскале были написаны ... в каком формате фильтры заданы. что такое "фильтр" вообще - это условие формата "Столбец N"=X ?

Comment: расписал по подробнее

Comment: Как то у вас "подробнее" и "понятнее" совершенно разные вещи. Я например окончательно запутался что требуется.  По моему пониманию "фильтр" это некие значения на основе которых надо произвести отбор строк из некого множества. Если вам надо просто перебрать все возможные варианты условий, то куча вложенных циклов, каждый по своему столбцу. Если по каждому в отдельности то над тем что у вас есть один цикл который перебирает столбцы

Comment: да, надо перебрать все возможные варианты, но если делать кучу вложенных циклов, то там надо делать 64 "Если"

Comment: конечно, много. Заменим факт включения столбца в комбинацию - 0 или 1, т.е. в общем получим число с количеством бит равному количеству столбцов, и для последнего примера - это 2 в десятой степени различных вариантов, =1024. И нужно 'прощупать' их каждый. Тут много 'Если' пнадобится